# Why does FragmentManager's BackStackEntry is 0 even though I perform addToBackStack(null)

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
private BaseFragment fragment;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager1;
private FragmentTransaction aFragmentTransaction;
```

This is the code in my OnCreate() method:

```
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, 
fragment).commit();
fragmentTitle = getResources().getString(fragment.getFragmentTitle());
setTitle(fragmentTitle);
```

.... Some more code...

```
aFragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
aFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
aFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
aFragmentTransaction.commit();
setTitle(getResources().getString(fragment.getFragmentTitle()));
```

This is the code in the same activity in the method OnBackPressed():

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

fragmentManager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
if (fragmentManager1.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
    fragmentManager1.popBackStack();
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Both are in the same Activity.
When I debug, BackStack has 0 elements.

EDIT: After executing aFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null), BackStack still remains null

Comment: Why do you have two FragmentManager references and why do you keep a reference to that FragmentTransaction?

Comment: I removed the fragmentManager1, there's indeed no reason for it. I'm new to Fragments so i'm not sure if i'm doing everything right

Answer (score 0):

Because you replaced it instead of add it. do like this:

```
aFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
```